# Jquery determine the media currently playing in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently maintaining a large Jquery app. There is this bug that plays a background music, though it shouldn't. Most probably it's coming from a `<video>`. To look for it's root cause, is there a way to determine the currently playing video or get a property that states that the media is currently on play?

Comment: You should be using ` currentSrc`

Go through http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-currentsrc

Answer (score -1):

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("myMediaElementID");
mediaElement.pause();
```

Code examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: `var mediaElement = document.getElementById("myMediaElementID");`

How do you know the ID?

Comment: @harsha, it is for example.

Comment: It's an example for pausing media,not to determine the media